# Android - using different SharedPreferences, how do I get the same values?

Tags: android

I just realized that in different Activities, I use different SharedPreferences.  For example, I have things like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
    getDefaultSharedPreferences( LoginActivity.this);
```

and

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
    getDefaultSharedPreferences( ProblemioActivity.this);
```

and then I have been putting data into the prefs object.

But my data seems to persist. How is that possible?  Should I have been using something like this:

```
activity.getSharedPreference("SomeKey", Mode);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't different shared preferences. They are the same! In both cases, you are passing the application context via the activity instance.

To use multiple shared preferences, you can specify a name with [`Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)